# Google API: Get Refresh/Access Token on each run

Tags: php, google-api

I am making a HTTP GET Request to the googleapi page to return information regarding my adsense account. When I do this, I send a header of `Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN` but the Access Token is only valid for 1 hour. How would I get a new Access Token the next time I run my script *without using the browser*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saving access token, save refresh token too (in authorization code exchange)

then, use refresh token to get new access token after 1 hour